# Transit visa in India for Bangladeshi

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, india

I've five Bangladeshi workers returning home to Bangladesh after the completion of their contract. Their flight is from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) to Bangladesh (DAC), and they have a transit in Kolkata (CCU), India for 7-8 hours. Do they need a transit visa in India?

Answer (score 2):

As per Timatic, they are entitled to TWOV (transit without visa) if they do not leave the airport:

> Destination - Bangladesh (BD)
>
> Passport
>
> Passport required.
>
> Document Validity:
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry
>   must be valid on arrival. Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>   Passengers with a handwritten passport are not allowed to enter.
>   Warning: Passengers with a handwritten extension on a machine readable
>   passport are not allowed to enter Bangladesh.
>
> Transit - India (IN)
>
> Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket
>   for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
>   international transit area of the airport and have documents required
>   for the next destination.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> Holders of visas
>   that specifically state the city/airport of entry must enter India at
>   the specified city/airport. Hotel facilities are available in Terminal
>   3 at Delhi (DEL) for passengers with a boarding pass for their
>   connecting flight.